# python/flask opening a text file in flask

Tags: python, flask

with open(url_for('static', filename='bmidata.txt') as f:

the above line causes a syntax error (marked at the 'as'). The code is part of the following:

```
@app.route('/display')
def display():
page_info = {
    'title':'Assignment Flask',
    'heading': 'Python Flask Assignment'
}
filedata = []
with open(url_for('static', filename='bmidata.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        str = line
        dataarray = str.split(',')
        it =iter(dataarray)
        name = it.next()
        height = it.next()
        weight = it.next()
        newPerson = Person(name, height,weight)
        filedata.append(newPerson)

return render_template('display.html', info = page_info, fileinfo = filedata)
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Un-closed parenthesis before `as`. Besides `url_for` does not look like something you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

In this line:

```
with open(url_for('static', filename='bmidata.txt') as f:
```

you are missing one closing bracket:

```
with open(url_for('static', filename='bmidata.txt')) as f:
```

That's the reason for SyntaxError.

Opening file doesn't work this way, because `open` doesn't accept URL. If you need to open static file, use `with app.open_resource('static/bmidata.txt') as f:` or find the path of the file on the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks Messa, got it working (still spent 15 minutes, trying to figure out what was wrong with open-resource,(should have course had open_resource). Need a break!